# Helper in custom Prestashop module?

Tags: module, prestashop, helper

Can anyone tell me how can we use helper in Prestashop module?

I want to display form fields with the help of the helper.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference in using helpers in core & in custom modules, just take a look at some of the core modules that use the specific helper.

Official documentation:

- [For PrestaShop 1.5](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Helpers)
- [For PrestaShop 1.6](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+Helper+classes)